# solving this probability

Tags: probability

Three Cards are drawn successively,without replacement from a pack of 52 cards.Then the probability that the drawn cards are Face cards of same suit,is

My Analysis: No of Events:   Event A-Getting first face card from the same suit

```
                         Event B-Getting second face card from the same suit
                       Event C-Getting  Third face card from the same suit
                       Sample Space- No of elementary elements of the cards/No        
                                     of ways to pick up the cards
```

Selecting a suit can be done in 4C1 ways.Also each suit contains 3 face cards

So, P(A):4C1X 3/52

```
   P(B):4C1X 2/52

   P(C)-4C1X 1/52

   n(D):52
```

I am getting stuck after this.I know this is conditional probability because the events are dependent to each other but how should i proceed after this.Any suggestions

Comment: Is an ace a face card?  You can't get another ace of the same suit on the second draw because it is without replacement and there is only one.

Comment: sry ,i miswrote that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to remember that

- there are a total of $12$ face cards in $4$ suits
- drawing is without replacement
- at the start, you can draw any of the $12$ face cards, but later, only face cards from the same suit.

Thus $Pr = \frac{12}{52}\cdot\frac2{51}\cdot\frac1{50}$

Comment: Btw, an ace is **not** considered a face card (do you see a drawing of a face on it ?)

Comment: But how can we multiply if the events are not independent? also can u explain how did u  get that 2/51 probability,Is it bc once you get the face card in first turn ,your suit gets decided?

Comment: We are taking care of non-independence simply by recognizing that with each draw, the remaining sample space is reducing. We are using the *general* multiplication rule, e.g. for two events, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$. The alternative way to solve this problem would be to use combinations.  [Choose a suit]$\times$[choose $3$ face cards from that suit] /[Choose any $3$ cards] viz. $\dfrac{\binom41\binom33}{\binom{52}{3}}$

Comment: Can u explain the multiplication rule more with some example as i think it is main difficulty while solving such problems.I thought we can multiply only when events are independent but solving three events with conditional probability seems a tough one for me.

Comment: You can have a look at the basic probability rules at https://www.google.co.in/search?q=probability+rules&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=bzEJWsXiKKSA8QfMwbPIDQ and continue on to *conditional probability* at the same site. Basically, it is just a chain process. You know how to find $P(A\cap B)$, and
$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P\big((A\cap B)\cap C\big)
= P\big(C\mid(A\cap B)\big)P(A\cap B)$

Comment: thnx,this clears my doubt

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: @true blue anil  if the intersection of events is not empty,will there always be conditional probability?

Comment: @harambe: No, not always. $P(A\cap B)$ for non-disjoint events will involve conditional probability only if the two events are **dependent**.  If they are **independent**, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$

Comment: So only these two cases are there so we can solve the question according to this info,right?

Comment: @harambe: In **this** question of drawing cards, even if two cards are drawn w/o replacement, the two events are dependent.

Comment: i was talking about any general question involving intersection of events

Comment: will u answer pls

Comment: this will help me so much

Comment: For events where the intersection of events is not empty, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ if the events are *independent*, and $P(A) P(B|A)\; or\; P(B)\cdot P(A|B)$ if the events are *dependent*

Comment: Thanx,you are the best!